# In Exercises3–12, determine whether each set equipped with the given operations is a vector space. For those that aren't identify the axioms that fail

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

[image]

I'm having trouble with these three questions in particular. how do I determine if the form (x,0) passes these axioms? and how do I do this with matrices? and how with polynomials like #12?

Comment: You check the axioms explicitly, though I suspect your problem lies your understanding the operations of these (possible) vector spaces. For example in question 3, you can add elements like so: $(x,0)+(y,0)=(x+y,0)$ and multiply by scalars like so: $k(x,0)=(k \cdot x,k \cdot 0)=(kx,0)$. Now check the relevant axioms. For the other two, figure out the 'sum' and 'scalar multiplication' operations.

Comment: Number 8 assumes you know about matrix addition and scalar multiplication, also that you know what it means for a matrix to be _invertible_. Do you need any help with those things?

Comment: i know matrix addiction and scalar multiplication. I believe for a matrix to be invertible ad-bc must not = 0 if i remember correctly?

Comment: Hint for 8: $I_2$ is an invertible matrix and hence so is $-I_2,$ but is their sum an invertible matrix?

Comment: @JL: you remember correctly and you can apply those things to the hint just given.